# INSERT with subquery can't bind reference to target table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, sql-insert

I'm trying to consolidate two columns in a table into a foreign key reference to another table that contains those same two columns.  I first want to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Securities (SubIndustID) 
    SELECT ID FROM dbo.SubIndust
        WHERE dbo.SubIndust.GICS_Sector = dbo.Securities.GICS_Sector
        AND dbo.SubIndust.SubIndustry = dbo.Securities.SubIndustry;
```

I get an error message for each reference in the sub-query to a column in the destination table:

***The multi-part identifier "dbo.Securities.GICS_Sector" could not be bound.***

***The multi-part identifier "dbo.Securities.SubIndustry" could not be bound.***

Why is the correct way to make this foreign key substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention the table in the `from` clause if you want to use it elsewhere in the query.  This would be a more syntactically correct version:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Securities (SubIndustID) 
    SELECT i.ID
    FROM dbo.SubIndust i JOIN
         dbo.Securities s
         ON i.GICS_Sector = s.GICS_Sector AND
            i.SubIndustry = s.SubIndustry;
```

However, I suspect that you really want an update:

```
update s
    set s.SubIndustID = i.Id
    from dbo.Securities s JOIN
         dbo.SubIndust i
         on i.GICS_Sector = s.GICS_Sector AND
            i.SubIndustry = s.SubIndustry;
```

Comment: Great!  (Of course you are also correct that this should actually be an UPDATE statement.